# Failure to build a project using NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying out NDK for the first time, and I'm stuck with building this project. I'm attempting to use the libraries used in Android's screencap recording program to read data from my screen. I understand that I need to use LibGUI, which I've pulled from my phone. Whenever I compile, however, I get this as an error message:

```
C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/ScreenCapture//jni/main.cpp:2:34: fatal error: gui/ISurfaceComposer.h: No such file or directory
```

Which is odd, considering that I have libgui.so included.

What my main file looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gui/ISurfaceComposer.h>

int main() {
    printf("Started!");
    return 0;
}
```

What my Android.mk looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libgui-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libgui.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := screencapture
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libgui-prebuilt

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

And I have both the main file and libgui.so in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

> main.cpp:2:34: fatal error: gui/ISurfaceComposer.h: No such file or directory

Your error message indicates that the **compiler** is unable to find a **header** file, but your attempted solution is to provide a shared object (.so) **library** from the phone.

Libraries might help at link time, but before you can link you must successfully compile, and to do that you are going to have to obtain the missing header (perhaps from AOSP sources, as source code it will not be found on the phone) or else recreate it by deducing its contents from clues you collect.  Unfortunately, it often isn't possible to take just one internal header out of AOSP, as it will likely depend on many others.

**Linking against private system internals also introduces a risk of your program breaking if the private interface between internal components changes between Android versions.**

(Normally I would also mention that you are unlikely to be able to record a screen with the NDK in it's normal usage of making a shared library to link into an application process, however your Android.mk seems to indicate you are building an executable - that *might* work if you can succesfully build it **and you run it as a user with sufficient permission** such as adb's `shell` userid or using a root hack)

Comment: I had a feeling that I needed the actual header files. I was under the impression that using LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include would extract them from the libraries, but I guess I'm wrong. Also, I'm not worried about changes in Android versions, as I'm just making something for personal use. This will all be done on a rooted phone.

Comment: Native libraries do not include headers, and if they are built from C (or otherwise without C++ name decoration) likely include precious little information usable to deduce them.

Comment: Got it. What I'm basically trying to do is access ScreenshotClient.update() to retrieve the screen's pixels. It seems to be the fastest way of doing so, yielding a much higher FPS than querying fb0.

Answer (score 0):

Add one line for module screencapture:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/
```

If you haven't folder gui, you need to copy&paste includes headers *.h into folder jni/gui. Always such a requirement about using like that for ndk...

---

Or second case - using other location of this source for ldlibs:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/full_path_to_source_gui/gui/
```